# Why do I get EBUSY when trying to pthread_mutex_destroy?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

Right before exiting, I call from the `main()` in the following order to:

1. `pthread_cancel()` other threads uses `mtx` which are "waiting" (**They are waiting for other *cond_variable and mutex*. Maybe that's the problem?**
2. `pthread_cond_destroy(&cnd)` (which is "coupled" whith `mtx`)
3. `pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx)`
4. `pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx)`

However, the last function results `EBUSY`. Each time another thread uses the mutex it almost immediately release it. Also, as mentioned, I kill all those threads before trying to destroy the mutex.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Why are you using a mutex on just one thread? Perhaps just to slow it down!

Comment: @EdHeal, please see edit.

Comment: Were the threads which got cancelled running detached? If not, did the code join them?

Comment: Is there a more graceful way to terminate threads rather than killing them

Comment: I do not join them because they behave as workers which go to sleep when the queue is empty.

Comment: So I need to use `pthread_detach()` instead of `pthread_cancel()`?

Comment: Anyhow, they shouldn't be a problem because when they acquire `mtx` (for signaling the main thread) they immediately release it. So again, I am not sure why do I get `EBUSY`..

Comment: @LiorGolan: Do not use `pthread_cancel()` at all. And `pthread_detach()` is not to end a thread. Please RTFM.

Answer (score 2):

As per `man pthread_mutex_destroy`:

> The pthread_mutex_destroy() function may fail if:
>
> **EBUSY**
>       The implementation has detected an attempt to destroy the object referenced by mutex while it is locked or referenced (for example,
>   while being used in a pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait())
>   by another thread.

Check if the mutex is not used by another thread when you try to destroy it.

Comment: Okay, actually I do use `mtx` from another thread but when I do that I am also unlocking right after signaling. Moreover, I cancel all those thread before, so I really don't know why it happens...

Answer (score 1):

> pthread_cancel() other threads uses mtx which are "waiting" (They are waiting for other cond_variable and mutex.

Cancellation is running asynchronously to the cancelling process, that is `pthread_cancel()` might very well return before the thread to be cancelled ended.

This results in resources (mutexes, conditions, ...) used by the thread to be cancelled perhaps still being in use when immediately calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()` afterwards.

The only way to test whether cancellation succeeded it to call `pthread_join()`on the cancelled thread and expect it to return `PTHREAD_CANCELED`. This implies that the thread to be cancelled wasn't detached.

Here you see one possible issue with cancelling threads. There are others. Simply avoid all this by not using `pthread_cancel()`, but implement a proper design ending all threads in well defined manner.